# Differential equation with multiple solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The below was a question on exam and I solved it like the below..

$$y^{'}=3t^{2}+3t^{2}y$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=3t^2(1+y)$$

$$\frac{dy}{1+y}=3t^{2}dt$$

$$\int\frac{dy}{1+y}=\int3t^{2}dt$$

$$\ln|1+y|= t^{3}+C$$

$$e^{\ln|1+y|}= e^{t^{3}+C}$$

$$1+y = e^{t^{3}+C}$$

$$y= e^{t^{3}+C}-1$$

But the answer provided by the professor has two solutions to the problem and I don't understand what I did wrong..and there are no initial value like $y(0)=$ something given.

$$y(t) = -1$$ and $$y(t)=2e^{t^3}-1$$

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Your variables don't make any sense. Should the $dx$'s really be $dt$'s?

Comment: @TheCount yeah, just a typo..will fix it.

Comment: If what you have said is all true then I am honestly baffled. Perhaps an expert will find a subtlety. This isn't really my area but the problem seems fairly straightforward...

Comment: Yeah the more I look at this... the more puzzled I am at what your professor claims is correct. I will give this a thorough mulling over and come back if I realize anything interesting. But for now, might want to take this to a TA or something for clarification. Note though, for example, that $y(t)=-1$ *does* in fact solve the DE presented.

Comment: If $y_0=-1$, then $y(t) = -1$. If $y_0=1$, then $y(t)=2e^{t^3}-1$.

Comment: You solved this DFQ by using separation of variables. I don't think you made a mistake, however separation of variables sometimes does leave out some solutions, very often the x-axis and/or the y-axis. Meaning, one (or both) axis happens to be a solution of the DFQ, but it is not found in the solution obtained by separation of variables. One should check this independently.

Comment: When $y=-1$ you are dividing by zero on the third line, hence why that solution is missing. If you take that case, then the second line reads $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$ so $y$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is indeed $y=e^{t^3+C}-1=ce^{t^3}-1$, where $c=e^C$.

Now, there is no $C\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $c=e^C\le0$, but the second form is valid, even for $c\le0$ (just plug it into the differential equation).